# Specifying that a part of a regular expression should not contain another regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, matching

Is there a way to specify that a regular expression should not contain a match of another regular expression?

Which regular expression (given here in Javascript-style syntax) would correspond to the regular expression `/(artwork|sheep|cattle|book|literature)(s)/i`, but not containing matches of `/(sheep|cattle|artwork|literature)(s)/`?

Comment: Unclear... Do you mean you want r1 to match but not r2? What is the use case?

Comment: Looks to me like the regex for that is /books/

Comment: I want matches of the second regular expression to be excluded from the first regular expression.

Comment: I'm creating a wiki application where regular expressions are being used to specify redirects to other pages. There might be some instances where I don't want a regular expression to contain matches of another regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `/books/` is not the answer then perhaps try with negative look ahead.. like this

```
=> /(?!(?:sheep|cattle|artwork|literature)(?:s))(artwork|sheep|cattle|book|literature)(s)/
>> re =~ 'books'
=> 0
>> re =~ 'bookxs'
=> nil
>> re =~ 'sheep'
=> nil
>> re =~ 'cattle'
=> nil
>> re =~ 'test'
=> nil
```